# how to make the main thread wait twice successively(may be silly for you)

Tags: ios, swift

I am a newbie learner for ios. i am using xcode 6.1. I am working on a an exercise which i could not complete very easily. 
   The task has a page in which two labels and an image view are loaded from an array.The array contains the Sequential number corresponding text and corresponding image. The page must display the no first and then wait for 5 seconds and then display the text and image after a press of a button. I have successfully completed the task.But i am trying to do it a bit more further.I need to display the next set of array after 3 seconds which seems hard for me to complete. i'll post my code here

```
f=0
@IBAction func sequential(sender: UIButton) {

                var x = self.f
                // x is for array index 

                self.noDispLabel.text = String(i+1)
                // Displaying the number

                print("\(i)")
                // progress bar optional
                self.progressBar.setProgress(Float(t.a), animated: true)
                // imagearray is the name of the array 
                var content=self.imageArray[i]
                //delay of 5 seconds 
                var delay =  5.0 * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC)
                var time = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, Int64(delay))
                dispatch_after(time, dispatch_get_main_queue())
                    {
                        self.imageDisp.image=UIImage(named:content.imageName)
                        self.titleDispLabel.text=content.imageTitle
                        self.progressBar.setProgress(0.0, animated: false)
                }

                self.imageDisp.image=nil
                self.titleDispLabel.text=nil

                if( self.f < 4)  // I have only 4 set of elements in the array 
                {
                    self.f++
                }
                else
                {
                    self.f = 0  // the loop restarts again.
                }


    }
}
```

I am not using core data or plist concepts. My images are stores in the assets.
i know that i am using dispatch. Now i want the whole block to repeat for all the contents of the array but the problem where i got struck is after the completion of the first set the main thread loop has to wait for 3 seconds before going to the next array element. Could someone help me.

the flow should be like this

```
imagearray={ { int no1,string title1,string image1},{ int no2,string title2,string image2},.......... till image4}}

button action 
{  
    for loop till all array elements  are visited 
      {
             reset the NoLabel to nil
             reset the TitleLabel to nil
             reset the ImageView to nil
             now display the no1 from imagearray or for loop incrementation (i) in the NoLabel 
             wait for 5 seconds 
             display the title1 from imagearray in the TitleLabel
             display the image1 from imagearray in the ImageView   

             now wait for 3 seconds
       }// in the next loop no2,title2 and image2 are dispalyed and so on
  }
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a few research i found out the answer for this. The IBAction method has permission to update the UI only once for a single user touchup action.So even a working for loop inside the IBAction can produce only one UI update result.So the iteration part of the block must be place outside the IBAction method. The structure of the block is given below.

```
 @IBAction func sequential(sender: UIButton) {

    timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(Double(8), target: self, selector: "updateSequential:", userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
}
 var f = 0
func updateSequential(timer2:NSTimer)
{
   var x = self.f
            // x is for array index 

            self.noDispLabel.text = String(i+1)
            // Displaying the number

            print("\(i)")
            // progress bar optional
            self.progressBar.setProgress(5.0, animated: true)
            // imagearray is the name of the array 
            var content=self.imageArray[i]
            //delay of 5 seconds 
            var delay =  5.0 * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC)
            var time = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, Int64(delay))
            dispatch_after(time, dispatch_get_main_queue())
                {
                    self.imageDisp.image=UIImage(named:content.imageName)
                    self.titleDispLabel.text=content.imageTitle
                    self.progressBar.setProgress(0.0, animated: false)
            }


            if( self.f < 4)  // I have only 4 set of elements in the array 
            {
                self.f++
            }
            else
            {
                self.f = 0  // the loop restarts again.
            }
            if(self.q==0)     // q is a reference variable which is defined on another part of the block to stop the timer.
            {

               self.timer=NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(Double(8), target: self, selector: "updateSequential:", userInfo: nil, repeats: false)

            }
             else
            {

               [timer.invalidate]
               self.timer = nil
            } 
  }
```

This is how i am using the code which worked.thanks for lynda.com for sharing an amazing tutorial. Also for stackoverflow other questions. I forgot to back up the link of a answered question which actually gave me the idea for using NSTimer functions.Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

If you need something to happen 3 s after the first processing is completed in 5 s, you can add another delay of 8 s, 5 + 3, inside your function.

```
var delay2 =  8.0 * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC)
var time2 = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, Int64(delay2))
dispatch_after(time2, dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
    // Code to occur 3 s after the first set of delayed operations.
}
```

Comment: yes i tried that too. But i want to display all the contents of the array which leaves me no other choice but to use for loop which does not wait for the completion of the dispatch

Comment: Dispatch block is meant to execute when it was scheduled.

Answer (score 0):

Check this out, I have updated the solution... this might help you

```
var f = 0
    @IBAction func testSequential(sender: UIButton) {

        if self.f == self.imageArray.count - 1 {
            self.f = 0
        }


        //delay of 5 seconds
        var delayTime = 0.0

        for (var j = 0; j < self.imageArray.count; j++)
        {
            self.imgView.image=nil
            self.lblSecond.text=nil

            var time = self.delay(delayTime)

            dispatch_after(time, dispatch_get_main_queue())
            {
                self.logTime()
                // Displaying the number
                self.lblFirst.text = String(self.f+1)
            }

            delayTime += 5.0
            time = self.delay(delayTime)
            dispatch_after(time, dispatch_get_main_queue())
            {
                self.logTime()
                self.image(self.imageArray[self.f++])

                if self.imageArray.count - 1 == j
                {
                    self.progress.setProgress(Float(0.0), animated: false)
                }
            }

            delayTime += 3.0
        }
    }

    func image(index: Int) {
        let progressPer = Float(index)/Float(self.imageArray.count)
        self.progress.setProgress(progressPer, animated: true)
        let imageName = String(format: "%d", index)
        print(imageName)
        self.imgView.image=UIImage(named: imageName)
        self.lblSecond.text=imageName
    }

    func delay(var delayTime: Double) -> dispatch_time_t {
        delayTime =  delayTime * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC)
        let time = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, Int64(delayTime))
        return time
    }

    func logTime()
    {
        let date = NSDate()
        let calendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
        let hour = calendar.components(NSCalendarUnit.Hour, fromDate: date)
        let minutes = calendar.components(NSCalendarUnit.Minute, fromDate: date)
        let seconds = calendar.components(NSCalendarUnit.Second, fromDate: date)

        print("\n \(hour.hour):\(minutes.minute):\(seconds.second)")
    }
```

Comment: thanks for your tip but you misinterpreted  my concept i have edited my question to give you a clear idea about my problem.Once again thanks for your concern

Comment: Updated as per your requirement.